# Columnwise sum in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, key-value

I want to sum all the values by their places.

For example, given:

```
dict= {"adi":(1,2,4),"simon":(1,7,0),"lus":(3,1,2)}
```

I want to perform the following operation:

```
(1+1+3,2+7+1,4+0+2)----> (5,10,6)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you want to do. Do you have a question? Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to solve this

Comment: Since you asked half a question, I'll provide half an answer. `tuple(map(sum, zip(...`

Comment: BTW, depending on the version of Python you are using, you should **not** expect the same order in the output tuple (it can be any permutation of `(5, 10, 6)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `zip(*data.values())` to transpose the values in the dictionary, and then we can use `sum()` and a list comprehension to get our final result:

```py
[sum(val) for val in zip(*data.values())]
```

This outputs:

```py
[5, 10, 6]
```

Note that I'm using `data` rather than `dict` as a variable name, as the latter is the name of a built-in. Note also that this relies on the fact that dictionaries preserve insertion order, which is only true on Python 3.7+.

Comment: Sounds good. Remember to accept the answer you find most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all the keys k in the dictionary d, and for each k, add the 3-tuple d[k] to the current sum res:

```
d = {"adi":(1,2,4),"simon":(1,7,0),"lus":(3,1,2)}
res = [0,0,0]
for k in d:
    res = [res[i] + d[k][i] for i in range(3)]
print(tuple(res))
```